# How do you make the single page in Wordpress work, when changing the permalink structure?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I am using post_type_link hook to add a custom taxonomy into the permalink.  It works great except now the new permalink just redirects to the landing page - it is not using my single page. If you change the permalink for a custom post type how do you keep the single page working. Also a regular page now links to the landing page as well.  I have re-saved the permalinks in the WP admin and no luck.  Any ideas?

CODE:

```
function update_permalink_agendaitem( $post_link, $post, $leavename = true, $sample = false ){
    if (get_post_type($post->ID) == 'agendaitem') {
        if ( is_object( $post ) ){
            $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'agendaitemtype' );
            if( $terms ){
                return str_replace( '%agendaitemtype%' , get_post_type($post->ID) . '/' . $terms[0]->slug . $post->slug , $post_link );
            }
        }
    } else {
        return $post_link;  
    }
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'update_permalink_agendaitem', 1, 3 );
```

Then when building the post type:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => '%agendaitemtype%', 'with_front' => false)
```

Comment: Hi, Jack. Can we see your code please?

Comment: Code added above...

Comment: Any ideas?  I'm stumped...

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: so I think what I need to do is reroute to the appropriate single page based on CPT type.  I found the code below to do this but it looks like this hook single_template never gets called???

```
  function update_single_templatee( $single_template ) {
    wp_die("WHEN DOES THIS FIRE???");
  }
  add_filter( 'single_template', 'update_single_template', 11 );
```

...nothing happens. I've tried with different priorities and still nothing...

Comment: This is not an answer, please [edit] your question with new information.

Answer (score 0):

So...it seems like.  If I try and use the hook post_type_link to update the URL structure (from my first bit of code above), then the single_template hook (my second bit of code) no longer fires for the CPT.  If I take out the post_type_link hook callback then the single_template hook fires.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).